# Cannot find module '@tridnguyen/config' | Install npm grunt

Tags: node.js, git, npm, gruntjs

Getting error while running grunt after installing npm.

```
C:\Users\XXXX\git\projectname\cartridges>grunt
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module '@tridnguyen/config'
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes either git is not installed in your system or git is not set in PATH.

Expected root cause and solution:

Download git from https://git-scm.com/download/win if not installed

If installed but missed to set it in path then set following address of git in PATH.

```
;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

Reopen run the command prompt after closing it and then run the command again. `npm install --save @tridnguyen/config`

This time command should be executed successfully.

Also visit: http://www.clearfunda.com/ to find more knowledgeable stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell as you do not show us your `package.json` nor your `Gruntfile.js`.

But as the error says, the module *@tridnguyen/config* was not found.
So you should start by install dependencies:

```
npm install
```

or, if this is a new project:

```
npm install --save @tridnguyen/config
```

Also there is a *grunt* warning because there is no registered default task in your `Gruntfile.js` file.

You may want to add one if you want to use `grunt` command:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ["your_default_task"]);
```

You should also take a look at the [Grunt documentation](https://gruntjs.com/getting-started) to become more familiar with that.